# Moses on windows via cygwin - boost does not seem to be installed or g++ is confused

Tags: boost, cygwin, moses

I want to use the machine translation tool Moses on Windows platform with cygwin. I have the "boost" lib installed from Cygwin(libboost_XXX.dll.a under /cygwin64/lib/).

When I tried to compile mosesdecoder (I have copied it under cygwin folder), but I got the error like this:
"boost does not seem to be installed or g++ is confused"

Do anyone knows what the problem might be?

Thanks.

Comment: One would hazard a guess that boost does not seem to be installed or g++ is confused.  Have you told it where to find boost?  Does [this site](http://www.statmt.org/moses/?n=Development.GetStarted) help at all?

Comment: I have told it the boost path but it didn't work. But thanks anyway. I have changed to linux since cygwin is a little bit fuzzy

Comment: I experienced the same issue when trying to build Moses with Visual Studio on Windows 10. Downloaded Boost, added paths as environment variables, nothing worked.